# Can't compile python plugin in QGIS (Windows)

Tags: qgis, python, error, windows, compile

I'm just installed QGIS 2.2 and created a new plugin from Plugin Builder. When I try to compile the plugin using:

C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin>pyuic4 -o C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin\
myplugin\ui_myplugin.py C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin\myplugin\ui_
myplugin.ui

I received the error message "Error: one input ui-file must be specified".

Someone could help me solve this issue? I'm running over Windows 8 OS.

Thanks,
Mateus

Comment: Could be an issue of spaces in the file paths

Comment: It's definitely an issue with spaces: you need to quote the file names. There also might be a typo: the last "_" is followed by a space which you probably do not want to be there.

Answer (score 3):

Open cmd and go to the folder "myplugin" (with comand "cd").

Then run:

```
pyuic4 -o ui_myplugin.py ui_myplugin.ui
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help. Unfortunately I tried this before and I receive the error message: "'pyuic4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.". To solve this issue I must run pyuic4 from the folder "C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin"

Comment: You could also run it as ```"C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin\pyuic4"```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by underdark and whuber, the white-space characters matter.

whuber pointed out that you probably have a typo in the `ui_ myplugin.ui` name, which should be `ui_myplugin.ui`. If so, you also have extra space in the `bin\ myplugin` in the first file path parameter. That should be `bin\myplugin`

There is a more general issue in that "Program Files" and "QGIS Valmiera" have spaces, so what you end up with (from the perspective of `pyuic`) is an output file of "C:Program", and extra arguments of "Files\QGIS", "Valmiera\bin\", "myplugin\ui_myplugin.py", "C:\Program, "Files\QGIS", "Valmiera\bin\myplugin\ui_" and "myplugin.ui". Each space delimits arguments.

So you should probably use:

`pyuic4 -o "C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin\myplugin\ui_myplugin.py" "C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin\myplugin\ui_myplugin.ui"`

Comment: Hello Brad and thanks for your help. You're right. I solve the issue adding "" as you described. Thanks!!! However, now I receive another error message: "Error: Permission denied: "C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin\myplugin\ui_myplugin.py". I believe this is because windows don't allow me to write in this folder. Do you know how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open OSGeo4W Shell from Start Menu/Screen, it should be installed.
2. Use change directory command *cd*

   ```
   cd "C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin\myplugin\"
   ```
3. Execute command without paths

   ```
   pyuic4 -o ui_myplugin.py ui_myplugin.ui
   ```

I think calling it directly on windows confuses things because pyuic4 is actually a batch file that executes some python script and somewhere along the lines the paths get lost.  Seems easier to let the OSGeo4W shell handle things.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran in the same problem with the current QGIS 2.6.1 by just typing make I had the same error. I've searched for the pyuic4.bat file and it was located correctly. SO I just used the absolute path in the OSGEO4W Shell:

```
C:\Users\ricckli\.qgis2\python\plugins\qgis2leaf>make
pyuic4 -o ui_qgis2leaf.py ui_qgis2leaf.ui
make: pyuic4: Command not found
make: *** [ui_qgis2leaf.py] Error 127
```

This one was working without a problem:

```
C:\Users\ricckli\.qgis2\python\plugins\qgis2leaf>C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\pyuic4 -o ui_q
gis2leaf.py ui_qgis2leaf.ui
```